# Does "one of the [superlative adjective]" need to be followed by a noun?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, ellipses, superlative-degree

> Luis is one of the tallest in his class.

In this sentence,  after tallest, should we use a noun or not?

Comment: *'He is one of the best'* is a common line from superhero films, so it is acceptable.

Comment: This usage even has a name (nominal adjective) and I'm almost sure that even the superlative variant has been covered on ELU before.Certainly this [InternetGrammar article](ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/adjectiv/nominal.htm) has been cited. // Here, adding a postmodifier may make the nominal adjective less natural-sounding, but this example doesn't sound too bad.

Answer (score 0):

"Class" implies a group of schoolchildren, so the noun is not necessary to make the meaning clear. In some sentences involving a superlative, it might be necessary. "Maria is one of the tallest girls in her class, but Luis is taller than she is."